# Как узнать высоту строки ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

В моем приложении используется ListView, которая выглядит примерно так, как на прикрепленном изображении. Строка моего ListView кастомная и состоит из ImageView и TextView (xml-разметка прилагается). В ImageView грузится пиктограмма, которая создается после того, как пользователь сделает фото и оно, при помощи метода Bitmap.createScaledBitmap (Bitmap src, int dstWidth, int dstHeight, boolean filter), приводится к нужным размерам и сохраняется в памяти устройства. Таким образом, размеры пиктограммы (width, height) должны практически равняться высоте строки ListView.

Моя проблема состоит в том, что мне нужно узнать размеры пиктограммы (в пикселях) до того как в ListView появится первая запись и можно будет программно определить высоту строки ListView на данном устройстве.
Я пытался задать фиксированную высоту строки ListView в dp и использовать ее в методе Bitmap.createScaledBitmap (Bitmap src, int dstWidth, int dstHeight, boolean filter), предварительно переведя эту величину в пиксели на этом устройстве. Но все-равно, на устройствах с разной плотностью и диагональю ListView отображается не всегда корректно. У кого какие есть варианты решения этой задачи, буду благодарен.

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="66dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="2"
android:background="@drawable/item_background_selector"
android:id="@+id/item_layout"
android:gravity="center_vertical">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/Pic"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

<Space
    android:layout_width="20px"
    android:layout_height="20px" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/item_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|left|top">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:textColor="@drawable/item_text_selector" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Data"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:textColor="@drawable/item_text_selector" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Скрин-шот ListView]

Comment: `ListView отображается не всегда корректно` - например?

Comment: Я тестировал на 3х девайсах с разной диагональю экрана и плотностью пикселей (Samsung Note 3: PPI - 386, диагональ - 5.7 "; @anber Samsung Galaxy S4 mini: PPI - 256, диагональ - 4.3"; Samsung S5282: PPI - 133, диагональ - 3"; ). Высота картинки почему-то не соответствует высоте строки ListView. На разных экранах пикторамма либо меньше, либо больше, либо более-менее соответствует высоте строки ListView

Comment: Ну так задайте высоту картинки не wrap_content а конкретным числом в dp.

Comment: @anber спасибо. именно так я эту проблему и решил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задайте высоту картинки не `wrap_content` а конкретным числом в `dp`.

<sub>Ответ перенесён из [комментария](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/471912/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%83-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-listview#comment531144_471912) участника [anber](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176928/anber).</sub>